# Submitting a canvas element in a form

Tags: javascript, css, html, forms, html5-canvas

I have managed to get this far from various tutorials and answers posted on other questions but i am now stuck. I have this form

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" 
rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<body>

<form id="regForm" action="sqlIn.php" method="post">

<h1>Welcome</h1>
  <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
  <div class="tab">
    <div id="capture"><video id="player" autoplay><canvas id="canvas"> 
</canvas></video></div>
    <script src="camera.js"></script>

  <p><input placeholder="First name..." oninput="this.className = ''" 
name="fname">
  <input placeholder="Last name..." oninput="this.className = ''" 
name="lname"></p>
    </div>
    <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
  <div class="tab">How can we contact you whilst on site?
    <p><input placeholder="Phone number" oninput="this.className = ''" 
name="Dir_phone"></p>
  </div>
    <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
  <div class="tab">Who do you work for?
    <p><input placeholder="dd" oninput="this.className = ''" name="dd"></p>
  </div>
<!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
  <div class="tab">Please read our Induction:
    <p><input placeholder="Username..." oninput="this.className = ''" 
name="uname"></p>
  </div>
    <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
  <div style="overflow:auto;">
    <div style="float:right;">
      <button type="button" id="prevBtn" 
onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
      <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
  <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
  </div>

</form>
  <!-- Link to the javascript for form animation/flow -->
  <script src="form.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
'* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
 background: url(wood-is-at-the-heart.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}

#regForm {
  background-color: #ffffff;
   margin: 100px auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 3px #245223;
  font-family: Raleway;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 70%;
  min-width: 300px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

/* Mark input boxes that gets an error on validation: */
input.invalid {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}

/* Hide all steps by default: */
.tab {
  display: none;
}

button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#prevBtn {
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
}

/* Make circles that indicate the steps of the form: */
.step {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.step.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Mark the steps that are finished and valid: */
.step.finish {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
#player{
  display: inline-block;
  height:400px;
  width:500px;
  margin: 0px;
}
#capture{
  diplay:inline;
  padding: 0px;
  height:400px;
  width:500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

and Finally JS

```
var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
showTab(currentTab); // Display the crurrent tab

  function showTab(n) {
  // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[n].style.display = "block";
  //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
  if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
  }
  if (n == x.length - 1) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
  }
  //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
  fixStepIndicator(n);
}

function nextPrev(n) {
  // This function will figure out which tab to display
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
  if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
  // Hide the current tab:
  x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
  // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
  currentTab = currentTab + n;
  // if you have reached the end of the form...
  if (currentTab >= x.length) {
    // ... the form gets submitted:
    document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
    return false;
  }
  // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
  showTab(currentTab);
}

function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x,
    y,
    i,
    valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "") {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " 
finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}

function fixStepIndicator(n) {
  // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
  var i,
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
  x[n].className += " active";
}
// and the code to show camera and get the image to a canvas.
const player = document.getElementById('player');
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
const captureButton = document.getElementById('capture');

const constraints = {
  video: true,
};

captureButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  context.drawImage(player, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // Stop all video streams.
  player.srcObject.getVideoTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
});

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
  .then((stream) => {
    // Attach the video stream to the video element and autoplay.
    player.srcObject = stream;
  });
```

I have tried various options of putting the canvas image in a variable and then setting a hidden input as that but cannot seem to get anywhere with it? i have all the other elements of the form being submitted by post to a mysql database

Once this is done i will be moving on to form logic and going to questions based on conditions then after that autofill to check if there is already an entry.  I am learning as i am going as my previous knowledge comes from before CSS was a thing. You can view it in codepen

See the Pen [Web Form](https://codepen.io/markarobinson/pen/WYaXdW/) by mark ([@markarobinson](https://codepen.io/markarobinson)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

I will try my best to answer any questions if more information is needed.

Thank you

Comment: Afaik, canvas elements do not count as input elements of a form so you do need to use hidden inputs or do the POST request manually so you have full control over the data that gets posted inside the script instead of relying on the default <form> behaviour.

Comment: Yes, the image is taken from a video input then drawn in a canvas, it is the next step that i am struggling with. Would prefer it to be uploaded to a file and the url ket in the database but for the amount of images i will be storing a BLOB may be suitable. Like i say i only have rough understanding and this is a learning exercise more than anything. thank you for the answer.